# combine different columns of date and time into one column as a date time

Tags: r

I have a bunch of character date and times that I would like to merge into 1 column of date time.

For example I have:

```
Date           Time
1/1/2018       2:00:00 PM
1/1/2018       9:00:00 AM
```

I would like the result to end like:

```
Date time
2018-01-01 14:00:00
2018-01-01 9:00:00
```

I first tried

```
paste(Date,Time)
```

but then I realized it does not take 'PM' into account when combining the two columns.

What should I do to merge the two columns in the correct format?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use use `as.POSIXct` after `paste`ing the 'Date' and 'Time' columns (assuming that the  Date format is month/day/year)

```
datetime <- with(df1, as.POSIXct(paste(Date, Time), 
            format = "%m/%d/%Y %I:%M:%S %p"))
data.frame(datetime)
#             datetime
#1 2018-01-01 14:00:00
#2 2018-01-01 09:00:00
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(Date = c("1/1/2018", "1/1/2018"), Time = c("2:00:00 PM", 
"9:00:00 AM")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -2L))
```

Comment: Thanks so much! I was trying with as.POSIXct() but that didn't really work. Now I know what went wrong. Thanks!